# How can I get rows for terminals? (vs. 'echo $COLUMNS')

Tags: scripting, terminal

I've finally gotten `ssh` onto my phone, but having done so, I realize that some of my ancient hard-coded scripts are very specific to an 80x24 resolution.

I'm aware that `$COLUMNS` will give me my 80, and allow me to do some things, but I'd like to figure out where I can access the other dimension of the terminal I'm getting to look at.

I'd hate to have to hard-code a set for every terminal, phone, or other hardware I might use, but right now it's looking like that may be the best option.

My phone gives me 53x13 with ConnectBot (couldn't find a better solution?), in case anyone cares.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/resize

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks, the answer to that question works for my current needs.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen as the question in the subject is more specific and is not addressed in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stty size` outputs the number of rows and columns of the current terminal; to extract the number of rows, keep the first field only:

```
stty size | cut -d\  -f1
```

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of `$COLUMNS` for rows is `$LINES`. That is set by some shells like `zsh` or `bash` (though in the case of `bash`, only when interactive) based on the tty device line discipline settings (themselves, usually set by the terminal emulator or in the case of `ssh`, by `sshd` from values supplied by the client (I don't know if `ConnectBot` sends those)).

You should be able to find the information in your shell man page. For instance, for `zsh`: `info zsh LINES`.

Other options:

- on some systems (and [that will be standard in a future POSIX version](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1053#c3863)), `stty size` returns the same information as `<lines> <columns>` on one line. On others, they'll usually show in the output of `stty -a` though in a format that varies from system to system.
- With the `ncurses` implementation of `tput`, you can use `tput lines` and `tput cols` to get the number of lines and columns (which can fall back to querying the terminfo database when the information cannot be retrieved from the terminal device).
- Some `xterm`-like terminal emulators (I don't know if that's the case of ConnectBot) let you query the terminal size via some escape sequences (`\e[18t`). For instance, with `zsh`:

  ```
  IFS=";" read -sd t $'ignore?\e[18t' lines cols
  ```

  to store the dimensions in `$lines` and `$cols`.
- with most terminals, instead of the `\e[18t` escape sequence, it's also possible to use (more common) escape sequences that move the cursor to the bottom right corner of the screen and query the cursor position there.  That's what the `resize` utility shipped with `xterm` actually does and can be used to align the tty settings to that and set `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` environment variables for those shells that don't do it already on their own:

  ```
  eval "$(resize -u)"
  ```

Comment: There's a typo and a factual error in the last bullet-point (see [this](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Miscellaneous)).

Comment: @ThomasDickey, thanks fixed (hopefully, assuming you meant that `\e[18t` was not _xterm-specific_).

Comment: Correct - the order seems to be shelltool, xterm, dtterm, xterm, rxvt (after which the trail is rather muddy regarding order...).  Someone might spend an afternoon making a chronological list :-)